# SQL Query Join not supported?

Tags: sql, vba, function, ms-access

I have a series of 4 tables that I need to loop through and pull information to make a new table in an access database:

```
SELECT *
  FROM tbl_f
 INNER JOIN( SELECT P, Area
               FROM tbl_l
              UNION ALL
             SELECT P, Area
               FROM tbl_m
              UNION ALL
             SELECT P, Area
               FROM tbl_w) ON tbl_f.P;
```

My Code includes:

```
Dim strSQL as string 

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_f inner JOIN( SELECT P, Area FROM tbl_l UNION ALL SELECT P, Area FROM tbl_m UNION ALL SELECT P, Area FROM tbl_w) ON tbl_f.P;"
```

I keep getting an error that the JOIN is not supported. I've used joins this way before, but any ideas?

Comment: You are not joining tbl_f to anything.  You need to alias the sub query and join on that.  `....SELECT P, Area  FROM tbl_w) as q ON tbl_f.P=q.p`;

Answer (score 3):

Your join syntax is not correct. Your updated query should look alike -

```
SELECT *
  FROM tbl_f
 INNER JOIN( SELECT P, Area
               FROM tbl_l
              UNION ALL
             SELECT P, Area
               FROM tbl_m
              UNION ALL
             SELECT P, Area
               FROM tbl_w) T ON (tbl_f.P = T.P);
```

Answer (score -1):

The bottom line with the "on" is your problem.

Missing an "=" along with whatever you are joining on:

```
FROM tbl_w) ON tbl_f.P = SOMETHING
```

Maybe consider an outer join if you want to include nulls for blank rows